# Automatic lock screen does not work in EL Capitan

Tags: security, macos, screensaver, screen-lock

I have my preferences set so the screen locks 1 minute after sleep or after the screensaver goes up.  This used to work until I upgraded to El Cap.  Now no matter how long after the screensaver has gone up I never get asked my password, the lock screen just does not happen.  Any idea why?

[image: Screen Lock preferences]

Comment: Same problem in Yosemite.  Same resolution (rebooting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can report the problem seems to have resolved 'naturally' after a reboot.  It is unclear why though.

Comment: I have this issue in 2017 on High Sierra 10.13 (17A405). Rebooting "fixed" it for me. But this is a serious security issue and it must not happen, ever :/